# Visualizing Charts Tutorial

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, data-visualization, twilio

I'm wondering which JS library would be best to dynamically visualize survey data from a postgres db.  I've been looking at morris.js, google visualizations, rapael.js, and D3.  The survey `has_many` questions which in turn `has_many` answers whose votes' columns are incremented by one per an SMS vote(using Twilio).  So I'm looking for a charts library that could dynamically update each time my controller receives an SMS, be easy to learn, and ideally have a couple tutorials related to what I'm trying to build.

What have you used and prefer?  Any recommendations?  Thanks!!

Comment: without any doubt...d3.js!!!

Answer (score 1):

2 big players in this!!!raphael.js and d3.js

D3 for obvious reasons:

1. based on current web standards(html5,javascript)
2. good documentation
3. powerful,robust and reusable
4. jquery style selection

the only place where raphael defeats d3 is fallback,raphael supports older versions of IE where as d3 is based on current web standards(IE>9)